# After apt install the package is executable but can't remove it

Tags: ubuntu, apt, apt-get, package-managers, tex

After successfully installing the dvips package, it shows up:

```
Step 1)
root@CCNM-378B:~# dvips -v
This is dvips(k) 5.997 Copyright 2017 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
```

But now I'm trying to remove it, and it is invisible to apt:

```
Step 2)
root@CCNM-378B:~# apt purge dvips
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'dvips' is not installed, so not removed
```

Now I try dpkg, which shows nothing:

```
root@CCNM-378B:~# dpkg -l | grep "dvips"
```

Finally, I tried 'apt list' and there are dvips fonts, but nothing else.

```
root@CCNM-378B:~# apt list | grep "dvips"
dvips-fontdata-n2bk/bionic 0.0.2001.12.12-4 all
```

So I search for the reverse dependencies (another package that may have installed dvips) using apt-cache:

```
apt-cache search dvips
```

and got a list.  And successfully removed them all.

**But doing Step 1 and 2 above, trying to remove dvips, still doesn't work, and dvips is still installed.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do:

```
$ dpkg -S $(which dvips)
```

And that should tell you the package that contains dvips.

You can from there use apt remove or `dpkg --remove` to remove the package

Some of the reasons that come to mind for this to happen are:

- the command being part of a package named very differently
- the package being installed outside of apt.

Comment: That worked!  Among the long list was texlive-binaries.  Knowing that divips is a part of texlive I just did 'apt purge texlive-binaries' and that did it.  For some reason, other texlive packages had showed up in the query I described in the question, but not this one.  Many thanks.